# How to update the items on hand quantity with QuickBooks Online Plus

Tags: json, quickbooks-online

I am using QuickBooks Online Plus, which means i can edit the item. I would like to use the API to change the on hand # for an item. I've created an item "test1" through QuickBooks Online Plus. When i read the item from API i got the following in the attached json file. things looks great as follow:

```
{
  "QueryResponse": {
    "Item": [
      {
        "Name": "test1",
        "Active": true,
        "FullyQualifiedName": "test1",
        "Taxable": false,
        "UnitPrice": 3,
        "Type": "Inventory",
        "IncomeAccountRef": {
          "value": "60",
          "name": "Sales of Product Income"
        },
        "PurchaseCost": 1,
        "ExpenseAccountRef": {
          "value": "61",
          "name": "Cost of Goods Sold"
        },
        "AssetAccountRef": {
          "value": "62",
          "name": "Inventory Asset"
        },
        "TrackQtyOnHand": true,
        "QtyOnHand": 6,
        "InvStartDate": "2015-12-02",
        "domain": "QBO",
        "sparse": false,
        "Id": "19",
        "SyncToken": "1",
        "MetaData": {
          "CreateTime": "2015-12-01T14:38:23-08:00",
          "LastUpdatedTime": "2015-12-01T14:38:42-08:00"
        }
      }
    ],
    "startPosition": 1,
    "maxResults": 1
  },
  "time": "2015-12-02T09:59:29.936-08:00"
}
```

But when i tried to update that item using the json object below:

```
{
        "Name": "test1",
        "Active": true,
        "Taxable": false,
        "UnitPrice": 3,
        "Type": "Inventory",
        "IncomeAccountRef": {
          "value": "60",
          "name": "Sales of Product Income"
        },
        "PurchaseCost": 1,
        "ExpenseAccountRef": {
          "value": "61",
          "name": "Cost of Goods Sold"
        },
        "AssetAccountRef": {
          "value": "62",
          "name": "Inventory Asset"
        },
        "TrackQtyOnHand": true,
        "QtyOnHand": 16,
        "InvStartDate": "2015-12-02",
        "domain": "QBO",
        "sparse": false,
        "Id": "19",
        "SyncToken": "2"
}
```

, i got an error like this:

```
{"Fault":{"Error":[{"Message":"Stale Object Error","Detail":"Stale Object Error : You and seven.li@hotschedules.com were working on this at the same time. seven.li@hotschedules.com finished before you did, so your work was not saved.","code":"5010","element":""}],"type":"ValidationFault"},"time":"2015-12-02T10:42:52.466-08:00"}
```

I would like to update the on hand quantity. Does anyone know what's wrong and how to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the "SyncToken". I believe when you try to update the new item, you should not increment the "SyncToken", you should keep it the same. QBO will update the "SyncToken" for you.